# a glue like substance in oil

Tags: oil, cooking-myth

I use refined sun flower oil (Fortune brand). Now I am realising that there is a glue like  substance in the  oil, also, it is so sticky that, the container in which in store has become dirty and gluey, also the gas burner has turned sticky. I have started using this oil since 6-8 months.

So is it because of the oil brand I use or any other oil also has the same effect

Answer (score 6):

It is not the brand. What you are seeing is just a bit of polymerisation, this occurs normally with thin layers of oil exposed to the air for a long time (on the bottle) and especially to a combination of air and heat (on the burner).

All oils polymerise to some degree. But if you buy a oil designed specifically for very high heat applications, you will see less polymerisation in the same time period, because these oils are less reactive chemically. Look for the "for frying" designation on the bottle, not the plant type - the amount of polymerisation is dependent not only on the source, but also on the cultivar (many companies are switching to seeds with a higher ratio of unsaturated fats, which polymerise easier) and the production process.

Comment: And keep the bottle farther away from your stove!